# Error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Customer'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I need to get all the customers from a different table that is customers into Tickets form.

My Modal....

```
public class Ticket
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required()]
    public Int32 TicketID { get; set; }
    public Int32 TicketNum { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public DateTime TicketDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Customer Name is required!!")]
    [Display(Name ="Customer Name")]
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }

    public Int32 FieldID { get; set; }
    public Int32 WellID { get; set; }
    public Int32 WellName { get; set; }
    public Int32 LogID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
  //  public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
   // public virtual Well Well { get; set; }
  //  public virtual Log Log { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
    {
        //Very important step
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(ticket);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Customer: ");

        ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(context.Customers.ToList());
        try {
              context.Tickets.Add(ticket);
              context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error:" , ex.Message);
            return View(ticket);
        }
        TempData["Message"] = "Created " + ticket.TicketID;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

My View.....

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TicketDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TicketDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TicketDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, "Customer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DropDownList("Customers", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(ViewBag.Customers), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I know there are number of posts on this and I tried everyone of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot name the `ViewBag` property the same as the property your binding to, but it appears you want to bind to `CustomerID` anyway, so your view should be (always use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods)

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(ViewBag.Customers), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
```

Next, the reason you get the exception is because `ViewBag.Customers` is `null`. You must reassign the value of the the `ViewBag` property if you return the view in the POST method. Assuming `Customers` contains properties `CustomerID` and `CustomerName`, then the code in the GET method needs to be

```
ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(context.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerName");
```

and in the POST method

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Reassign the SelectList
    ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(context.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerName");
    return View(ticket);
}
Console.WriteLine("Customer: ");

// ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(context.Customers.ToList()); Remove this
try {
    ....
```

Finally, based on the view you have shown, you need to remove property `public string CustomerName { get; set; }` which has a `[Required]` attribute, meaning `ModelState` will always be invalid. You have a dropdownlist for selecting the customer which needs to bind to `CustomerID` and you do not have a control for binding to `CustomerName` (and nor should you have one)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you so much for your quick reply. I tried What you have mentioned above...But My ViewBag.Customers is still null...I am not sure what is going on...my DB connection is fine and I also have data inside the Customers table....I am very new to MVC and really need to work this out as soon as possible....Please suggest

Comment: Then what is `context.Customers.ToList()` returning? Unless it returns `List<String>` then it will not work - it would need to be `ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(context.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerName");` (in both the GET and POST method) assuming `Customers` contains those 2 properties

Comment: Yes, The Customers table has those two properties..I tried checking the values returned by context.Customers.ToList() ...But I coulnt see any values at output console...Please advice me

Comment: Firstly I will edit my question. But if `context.Customers.ToList()` returns `null` then that is an entirely different issue as has nothing to do with any of the code you have shown

Comment: Looks like thats the issue...it is returning null

Comment: Because I tried creating an IEnumerable<Selectlist> cust in the modal itself and tried to view it as Modal.cust @View...it returned null there....I did check the Database connection which is fine..I am not able to debug this   And also..I have checked the Customer Table and it has values in there

Comment: `var customers = context.Customers.ToList()` will not return `null` (it might return an empty list if there are no items, but not `null`)

Comment: So what shall I do now?? PLease advice

Comment: My answer points out 3 errors you have in your code. Initially just test it by replacing using `@Html.DropDownList("Customers", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())` in the view. The error will disapear, although it wont display any options. As for why `var customers = context.Customers.ToList()` returns `null`, then you need to debug your code

Comment: Hi, Stephen..Thank you so much man...You have saved my day....All your suggestions worked....specially...Adding Viewbag to the Get method made it all the difference!!